# PHP CURL to get contents of a https page

Tags: php, curl, https

Example url:
    https://www.tescogoldexchange.com/gold-calculator.aspx?carat=9&weight=1&ref=miniQuote

I am trying to use cURL to get the contents of an HTTPS page.

Problem is that I am not able to grab the document and I have no idea why.

```
    function download_page($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");

    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're likely running into the same issue [this guy](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) is running into. And, he seems to have fixed it. The problem probably is the negotiation about the SSL certificate and how cURL should tell that the certificate the server is sending, can be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

Check for errors:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (!$result) {
   die(curl_error($ch));
}
```

most likely you're getting bitten by the fact that curl no longer ships with an internal list of 'valid' CAs, and therefore can't verify the remote site's certificate as valid. You'll have to disable cert verification, and/or install a list of CAs yourself

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

p.s. never assume that an operation on a remote resource succeeded - always check for error conditions, and output any error messages available. you'll save yourself a lot of heads cratching by having the lights on, rather than banging around in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided actually works fine for me, without modification. You may be having SSL-negotiation issues, as RolfVandeKrol mentioned. To try fixing with that idea, you can turn-off the SSL peer verification with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

To see what is actually going on, before modification, you can use `curl_getinfo($ch)` to view all of the headers returned. This should let you know what kind of response you're script is receiving for proper diagnosis.

In addition, you may want to modify your function to properly close the `curl` handle with `curl_close($ch);`. Try, instead of `return curl_exec($ch);`, using:

```
    ...
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $contents;
}
```