# How do you configure xdebug to work with https?

Tags: php, https, xdebug

I can't get xdebug to catch on a breakpoint using https, but it works fine with http.  Here is the xdebug config in php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
```

I've looked over the xdebug docs but can't find any mention of https.  Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with PHPStorm/IDEA. Had to change host port from 80 to 443 in Servers settings

`Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Servers`

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug shouldn't behave differently over SSL, so I suspect the problem to be in NetBeans. Can you try another client and see if that works? You can find a list of clients here: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: Led me on the right track, but not quite the solution for me.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue with curl passing the request along in the environment.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359647/php-curl-to-get-contents-of-a-https-page) for more help with that.